# java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested. in JBoss

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, wildfly, mysql-connector

I am having struts based application that runs on Wildfly 9.0.1.Final and database is MySQL.
Earlier the code use to run without any error. At that time JBoss version was 4.0.4.GA.

Now I have deployed code on Wildfly 9.0.1.Final and I am getting error when I add some new row.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Generated keys not requested. You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement().
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getGeneratedKeys(StatementImpl.java:1803)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.getGeneratedKeys(WrappedStatement.java:1105)
    at com.aldorsolutions.webfdms.database.DatabasePeer.insert(DatabasePeer.java:90)
    ... 48 more
```

Code:

```
    try {
                pstmt = getInsertSql((DatabaseTransaction)t,p);
                pstmt.executeUpdate(); // Execute the SQL

                ResultSet rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
                // ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY");

                if (rs.next()) {
                    autoinc = rs.getInt(1);
                    p.setId(autoinc);
                }

            } catch( SQLException e ) {
                // logger.error("SQLException in DatabasePeer.save: ", e);
                throw new PersistenceException("PersistentObj:" + p.getClass().getName() + " Message: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
```

Code for getInsertSql():

```
try {
                DbSpeedData item=(DbSpeedData)p;
                connection = t.getConnection();
                pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO speeddata (Identity, TabCategory, Locale, " +
                    "LocationId, TabData, SortSequence) VALUES (0,?,?,?,?,?)");
                pstmt.setString(1, item.getCategory());
                pstmt.setInt   (2, item.getLocale());
                pstmt.setInt   (3, item.getLocationId());
                pstmt.setString(4, item.getData());
                pstmt.setInt   (5, item.getSortSequence());
                return pstmt;
            }
            catch (java.sql.SQLException e){
                throw new com.aldorsolutions.webfdms.database.PersistenceException("DbSpeedDataPeer.Insert",e);
            }
```

I googled and found that I need to add 
`Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to the `pstmt.executeUpdate();`.

But the code earlier use to run properly on JBoss 4.0.4.GA and I have not changed code at all. Only change is JBoss upgraded to Wildfly.

What may be the issue?
Please help.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins can you give me any inputs on this ?

Comment: @TerrenceCurran can you ?

Comment: @BalusC can you contribute something on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you include the code for `getInsertSql`?

You'll need to pass the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` option when you create your `PreparedStatement`. eg:

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO speeddata (Identity, TabCategory, Locale, " +
    "LocationId, TabData, SortSequence) VALUES (0,?,?,?,?,?)",
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
);
```

Comment: Yes. I am adding that

Comment: But I am wondering I did not made any modifications to the source code and have just changed JBoss version.

Comment: Updated my answer... I'd be very surprised if it's a change in jboss version which caused this. Are you sure you haven't changed database driver too? I'd be very surprised if you could ever call `getGeneratedKeys()` without specifying `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

Comment: Yes that was working code without using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

Comment: One thing is that I am using mysql-connector version 5.0.5 in my code and on jboss I have deployed of version 5.1.36. Will that cause this issue ?

Comment: Your answer worked out. I am accepting that. But see my above comment.

Comment: I can't say for sure but a change in JDBC driver version is a much more likely source of the behaviour. Either way, by implementing my suggested change you are now using JDBC correctly... regardless of whether an old driver was allowing illegal usage.

Comment: Anyways I'll make versions sure are same

Comment: ohh was it illegal usage ?

Comment: please see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581253/mysql-connector-issues